# How to retrieve all existing indeces in painless

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I'm wanting to retrieve the number of indices in my ES cluster from within a scripted field of an aggregation.

I know you can access some context values with `ctx._source` but does anyone know how to get the total number of indeces from my cluster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. The `ctx` context has no idea about the state of your cluster. It has only access to the currently iterated doc.